# Can't get findstr to work with subprocess run on windows

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, findstr

I want to run findstr from my python environment and I can't get it to work when invoked using subprocess run (I am able to run the findstr command from the command line using a dos prompt):

```
commandlist = ['findstr', '/s', '"texttofind"', '*.py']
cwd = 'e:\\python'
shell = True
encoding = 'utf-8'
output = subprocess.run(commandlist, 
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                    encoding=encoding, shell=shell, cwd=cwd)
```

which ends up with returncode of 1:

```
CompletedProcess(args=['findstr', '/s', '"runrcode"', '*.py'],returncode=1, stdout='', stderr='')
```

If instead I use commandlist = ['path'] then everything works fine, resulting in returncode of 0 and stdout with the text listing for path as expected (of course shell has to be True for this to work).

Any ideas for how to get this to work? Not sure what I'm missing. Thanks so much.

Comment: can you type in a cmd window  `type findstr` ?
You can then try with the absolute path returned by type.

Comment: when I type "type findstr" I get "The system cannot find the file specified. I am updating my post above to add the fact that I am able to run the findstr command from the command line using a dos prompt.